# Change the sound from camera

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overriding iPhone shutter sound through SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247227/overriding-iphone-shutter-sound-through-sdk)

Is it possible to change the default sound of the camera, with a custom one when making a photo?

Comment: Jailbreak your iPhone and voila :)