# I wish i could mute shutter sound of camera using ios sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avfoundation

Right now I've been trying to mute my shutter sound when capturing an image in `iOS SDK` but unable to do it.
Is there any way of kind of code available for it
(Actually, I wanted to trace a fake person from my chat app)

I've seen:

- [Muting AVCapture shutter sound on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621252/muting-avcapture-shutter-sound-on-iphone)
- [How to mute the capture sound in AVFoundation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557081/how-can-i-mute-the-capture-sound-in-avfoundation)
- [AVFoundation, how to turn off the shutter sound when captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401232/avfoundation-how-to-turn-off-the-shutter-sound-when-capturestillimageasynchrono)

But I have not succeeded yet.

Comment: You should be aware that this is illegal in some countries

Comment: yes but it will be used for security purpose to trace fake person!

Comment: What is a "fake person"?

Comment: i meant fake user to prevent security

Comment: "Fake person" and "fake user" do not make any sense with regards to a camera.

Comment: I cant not share whole detail here.. sorry for that borrrden ..

Comment: Your details are not important.  The fact is that it is illegal in some countries and you shouldn't do it.  It is also likely against Apple's policy since I assume they don't want to break laws.

Comment: yeah i do know all that about apple ..anyway could you tell me how to do it?how it could be possible ?

Comment: borrrden need help if you could ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no way to programatically mute the shutter sound when capturing a still image. In most territories, muting the device in hardware (sliding the Mute button across) will mute the shutter sound, but not all—in Japan, for example it won't, because of legal restrictions.

Comment: Thanks Wildaker.. I m gonna leave that for a moment..