# Capture image via captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection with no shutter sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

There are a lot of questions about this problem on SO:

- [AVFoundation, how to turn off the shutter sound when captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401232/avfoundation-how-to-turn-off-the-shutter-sound-when-capturestillimageasynchrono)
- [How can I mute the capture sound in AVFoundation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557081/how-can-i-mute-the-capture-sound-in-avfoundation)
- [I wish i could mute shutter sound of camera using ios sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040309/i-wish-i-could-mute-shutter-sound-of-camera-using-ios-sdk)

But really no one answer works for me.

How do I capture an image programmatically without the camera shutter sound activating?