# How to mute AVCaptureDevice?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa

I have `cams` which is AVCaptureDevice, I made sure the flash was off but now I need to shut the camera noise up, is there a way to do that?

```
NSArray* cams = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDevice* device = nil;
    if(isBackCamera)
    {
        device = [possibleCameras objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else
    {
        device = [possibleCameras objectAtIndex:1];
    }

    device.flashMode = AVCaptureFlashModeOff;
```

Comment: did you see this one <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557081/how-can-i-mute-the-capture-sound-in-avfoundation?rq=1>

Comment: Did you check with any of these methods as well, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4432325/1730272

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that apple doesn't allow you to do that

Answer (score 0):

I was able to disable/mute the camera shutter sound while taking screenshot programmatically using the below code. Confirmed to work on iOS8.3 on iPhone 5 and accepted in App store.

```
MPVolumeView* volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] init];
//find the volumeSlider
UISlider* volumeViewSlider = nil;
for (UIView *view in [volumeView subviews]){
    if ([view.class.description isEqualToString:@"MPVolumeSlider"]){
        volumeViewSlider = (UISlider*)view;
        break;
    }
}

[volumeViewSlider setValue:0.0f animated:YES];
[volumeViewSlider sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```