# How do I open the app when local notification is tapped with the new notification mechanisms?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios10, uilocalnotification

`application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` is deprecated starting iOS10, and the [developer page](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622930-application?language=objc) doesn't point to any alternatives.

```
UNNotificationRequest* request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"localnotification"
                                                                      content:content
                                                                      trigger:trigger];


UNUserNotificationCenter* notificationCenter = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[notificationCenter requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionBadge | UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert)
                                  completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                          if (!error) {
                              NSLog(@"request authorization succeeded!");
                          }
                      }];


[notificationCenter addNotificationRequest:request
                     withCompletionHandler:nil];
```

I have created a notification as seen above with the appropriate content and trigger. Now I want the application to open when I tap said notification, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UILocalNotification is deprecated in iOS10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938771/uilocalnotification-is-deprecated-in-ios10)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I mute the capture sound in AVFoundation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557081/how-can-i-mute-the-capture-sound-in-avfoundation)

Comment: As per request I have edited my question to be more specific. The to duplicate possibilities do not answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter?language=objc)

This method from `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` needs to be implemented if you want to perform a custom action.

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    if ([response.actionIdentifier isEqualToString:UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier]) {
        NSLog(@"app opened");
    }
}
```