# Change iPhone Camera Shutter Sound in App

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapture

How can I change the sound that plays when an image is captured with an iPhone? I am using AVCapture and I want to capture still images (rather than grabbing frames from video) for image quality sake.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After more research it appears you can't. Video frame grabs would be the only way to go.

Comment: Alright. Well thanks for the info!

Comment: @JoshuaDance Jailbreak seems to be the only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching it appears that the standard camera shutter sound is next to impossible to change via SDK.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247227/overriding-iphone-shutter-sound-through-sdk) supports that.  You can replace your own sound, but not in an app.

As for AVCapture, it also appears that you can't change the shutter sound as capturing images covertly is against the App Store policy. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621252/muting-avcapture-shutter-sound-on-iphone)

The only way to take a silent picture is to use a video screen grab, which you said you don't want to do for image quality reasons.

So AFAIK, there is no way to change the shutter sound not using video screen grabs.